# Is there a way to uniquely style items in the wxChoice widget in wxPerl (WxWidgets)?

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, wxperl

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to style the items in a drop-down menu when I use the wxChoice widget. Best I can tell, it's not possible but I just wanted to ask the greater Perl community to make 100% sure that I was correct in my thinking.

My goal would be to color some of the items in the pull-down red, while others were black. I noticed that the wxChoice widget has the method SetForegroundColour, but this colors all the text in the wxChoice widget.

```
$driveCB->SetForegroundColour(wxRED);
```

Results in a pull-down looking like this:

[image: wxChoice example using SetForegroundColour]

Is it possible to individually style wxChoice items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a wxChoice, but you could use a [wxOwnerDrawnComboBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_owner_drawn_combo_box.html), there is an example of it in the wxWidgets samples, in the folder called combo.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. The link to the wxWidget samples is here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_samples.html. Specifically here's the link to the wxOwnerDrawnComboBox: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/combo/. The markup for the ComboBox is here: http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/samples/combo/combo.cpp?view=markup

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation says NO](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_choice.html)

Comment: Would be helpful if you included more constructive comments around why this isn't possible for other people that may stumble into this question in the future. I did read the documentation but it's a C/C++ library being used by Perl programmers so they may not be able to understand it.